# checking goodness of fit for Gompertz distribution in R

Tags: r

I know how to check for Weibull and exponential using fitdistr and ks.test.

but those don't work with Gompertz.

I think I need to use maxlik and rgompertz and ks.gompertz but I don't understand how to use maxlik to find the estimates of alpha and theta.

I found this in the maxlik pdf:

Estimate the parameter of exponential distribution

```
t <- rexp(100, 2)

loglik <- function(theta) log(theta) - theta*t

gradlik <- function(theta) 1/theta - t

hesslik <- function(theta) -100/theta^2

Estimate with analytic gradient and hessian

a <- maxLik(loglik, gradlik, hesslik, start=1)

summary( a )
```

How do I change it for Gompertz?

Comment: I think you need to understand the basics of Maximum Likelihood estimation first.  What is likelihood function and how to write it?  maxLik package is not really useful unless you are able to do that.

Comment: that's not a problem... i know Maximum Likelihood in depth and i know the loglik, and gradlik which is the 1st derivative of the loglik and hess which is the 2nd.

but rgompertz needs shape parameter that i don't know what to write

Comment: There are several examples to estimate normal distribution in maxLik.  That distribution has 2 parameters as well (and you can call sigma "shape" if you wish).  Would that help you any further?